# impose two mandatory tags in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Below is an example of gitlab-ci, i want to run the job on runner tagged **docker** and **prod**
example: if i have the list of runner below, i want that the job will be launched on the runner2:

- **runner 1** tags: `docker`, `preprod`, `shell`
- **runner 2** tags: `docker`, `preprod`, `prod`
- **runner 3** tags: `shell`, `preprod`, `prod`

how should i do please?

```yaml
buildWithDocker:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: build
  tags:
     - docker
  script:
     - echo 'Building with the docker executor...'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tags` key is a YAML array which accepts multiple values. As mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#tags) you can define multiple tags and the selected runner will have all of them:

```yaml
buildWithDocker:
    ...
    tags:
        - docker
        - prod
    ...
```

Comment: thank you what with what you propose it should be run on either runner1, runner2 and runner3. True?

Comment: @excellt No it should run on *runner 2* as you asked. Does it solve your issue ?